# How can I update duplicate rows in SQL server but leave the original?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Our SOP application went crazy and we now have thousands of duplicate documents in our Document Management System.

```
SELECT
    [INVOICE_NO],  COUNT(*)
FROM
    [dwdata].[dbo].[INVOICES]
GROUP BY
    [INVOICE_NO]
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

results in thousands of rows. Each invoice should only be stored once.

```
INVOICE_NO    |    COUNT(*)
2338508       |    2
2398800       |    3
2273807       |    2
2280570       |    4
```

Each row has a `DWSTOREDATETIME`. Example:

```
SELECT 
    [INVOICE_NO], [WORKSORDER], [DWSTOREDATETIME] 
FROM 
    [dwdata].[dbo].[INVOICES]  
WHERE 
    [INVOICE_NO] = 2338508

2338508    |    1571105    |    2015-11-16 13:52:41.910
2338508    |    1571105    |    2015-10-27 07:50:59.970
```

What I want to do is update `WORKSORDER` on the duplicate rows only (leave the oldest) to something made up such as `999999` that I know doesn't exist. I can then use the Document Management System deletion workflow module to delete based on that.

Comment: `SET WORKSORDER  = ROW_NUMBER() (PARTITION BY INVOICE_NO ORDER BY DWSTOREDATETIME)` just put rn to subquery/cte, then update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CTE, then it's simple:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.*, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY INVOICE_NO ORDER BY DWSTOREDATETIME ASC)
    FROM dbo.TableName t
)
UPDATE CTE SET WORKSORDER = 999999 WHERE RN > 1
```

If you want to see what you're going to update use `SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1`

Comment: I tested it using `SELECT * FROM CTE` as suggested and there are `INVOICE_NO` listed that are only present once in the database?

Comment: @user6888062: of course you need to apply the same filter as i did with the `UPDATE`, sorry that i've not included it. So `SELECT * FROM CTE  WHERE RN > 1`. The rows with `RN = 1` are the oldest of each `INVOICE_NO`-group. If you don't apply the filter you also find the groups without duplicate numbers.

Comment: Obviously, my bad. Thanks a lot. This seems to be what I needed and is running at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

You can update duplicate records like below. If you will run update statement multiple times then you need to add [WORKSORDER] column name also at partition clause in query to avoid unnecessary records from update statement.

```
UPDATE A SET WORKSORDER=999999
FROM 
(
SELECT
    [INVOICE_NO],WORKSORDER,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INVOICE_NO  ORDER BY DWSTOREDATETIME) RNO
FROM
    [DWDATA].[DBO].[INVOICES]
)A 
WHERE A.RNO>1
```